# How to solve laptop overheating problem on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: overheating

I just installed ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 7 laptop(Dell Vostro 1014) of mine. After two days I noticed serious overheating of my laptop. Since there aren't any easily accessible  option for down clocking processor rate, I'm at a loss now. Can anyone help me?
Laptop Configuration: http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/vostro-1014/pd

Answer (score 0):

You can set the CPU min/max frequency in the command line to see if it solves your problem:

`sudo apt-get install cpufrequtils`

To view your CPU profiles:

`sudo cpufreq-info`

To see how to set values:

`sudo cpufreq-set -h`

Your overheating problems could indicate old thermal paste on the CPU or dust in the system blocking airflow.  I try to clean my laptops out whenever I start having problems and will remove old thermal paste and re-apply.

I borrowed the `cpufreq` steps from here: http://www.overclock.net/t/790070/underclocking-for-overheating-in-ubuntu#post_10197274